# Best way to type hint a return value from a std library function not yet stubbed (pyodbc)

Tags: python-3.x, types

the pyodbc library has a `Cursor` object which has an attribute `description`. 
At the moment for me this is a seven element Tuple (I guess it may depend on the underlying database).

I would like to create a type and type hint Cursor.description with the minimum of fuss. At the moment I can make a Tuple, or even a 7 element Tuple, but I think I have to explicitly type-hint the returned value each time I use `Cursor.description`

Since I want this to be convenient, I'm hoping to I can do the type hint of Cursor.description in my .py file.

I can see that stub files exists (.pyi files) but I'm not sure if they help me do this, and they don't seem very convenient for this.